# What is the best type to hold an ordered pair of values of the same type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types

What is the best type to hold an ordered pair of values of the same type in C#?

By that I'd want that:

1. Two values composition is enforced at compile-time (no possibility of trying to add or remove at compile- or run-time).
2. Two values have the same static type.
3. Two values can be retrieved using an indexer (e.g.  pair[0], pair[1]).

   **UPDATE:** I changed my mind, I don't really want #3 anymore since it pointlessly opens the door to out of bound exceptions:

Comment: What about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx ?

Comment: No idea by what do you mean ordered pair of values, but you can use SortedDictionary. The first element would behave like a unique index though. Otherwise your best option is to go for tuple.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Comment: By ordered I just want to be specific that a Set would not suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extend the `Tuple` class like this:

```
public class Pair<T> : Tuple<T, T>
{
    public Pair<T>(T item1, T item2) : base(item1, item2)
    {           
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
       get
       {
           if (index == 0)
               return Item1;
           else if (index == 1)
               return Item2;
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
       }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added constructor.

Comment: That looks good, having to declare only one type rather than two.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: I also added a constructor (it wouldn't compile without it, I guess). You can use it like this: `var fnord = new Pair<string>("foo", "bar")`. You could also add a static Pair.Create method (like in Tuple), to have the type infered from parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from not having an indexer, [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) seems to match your needs.

```
Tuple<int, int> myPair = Tuple.Create(1, 2);
int firstValue = myPair.Item1;   // instead of myPair[0]
int secondValue = myPair.Item2;  // instead of myPair[1]
```

Of course, nothing prevents you from subclassing `MyPair<T> : Tuple<T, T>` and adding an indexer, if this is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a List of tuples like this :

```
var data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("string1","string2"));
Tuple<string, string> record = data[0];
```

Edit : in case you want it to be readonly :

```
public static readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("string1", "string2"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("set2", "set2b")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a plain array of 2 elements?

- Arrays are fixed-size, so elements cannot be added or removed.
- All elements are of the same compile-time type.
- You can use the indexer.

The disadvantage is that arrays of different sizes look the same to the type system, so you can't, for example, declare a function that receives only T[2] but not T[3]. If that's a problem, use [noah1989's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991774/533120).

Comment: C# arrays can have a static size?

Comment: @sixfeetsix [Yup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1026141/533120). That's why we _also_ need `List` for "non-fixed-size arrays".

Comment: One cannot change the size of an array at run-time?

Comment: @sixfeetsix Nope. You can redefine it (i.e. create a new array and assign it to a reference that used to point to the old array) but the existing slab of memory cannot be resized.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant that the _type of variable_ allows referencing arrays of different sizes, even though the length of the array _object_ is fixed.

Comment: @sixfeetsix Correct. Both `T[2]` and `T[3]` have the same type, which is `T[]`. Hence my comment about _inability_ to "declare a function that receives only T[2] but not T[3]".